# MySql : making a field unique for each article id

Tags: mysql, database, key

I just want to track unique visitors for each article page.
I made a table with 2 fields. `article_id` as **Primary** key and `ip`as **Unique**

The expected output should be like :

```
article_id    *       IP
52            -  100.200.300.400
52            -  20.30.20.40
52            -  30.40.50.60
93            -  108.207.302.403
93            -  10.30.20.40
```

But it's not working, this is what I get :

```
article_id    *       IP
52            -  100.200.300.400
93            -  10.30.20.40
```

I think I set the keys wrong.

Comment: ? what is your query and the what is the data in db ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `article_id` as **primary key**, you will never have two records with the same `article_id`.

To avoid duplication of `article_id` + `ip` pairs, you can define a UNIQUE index of **both** fields: `article_id` AND `ip`.

For example:

```
CREATE  TABLE `visits` (
  `article_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `ip` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_article_ip` (`article_id`, `ip`) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: I did define their data types as you said, but I don't get what u mean by "UNIQUE index of both fields". You mean I should make both of them Unique in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Oh Thanks! Sorry I didn't know an `AND` could be set between keys.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is also unique, so it will show up at most once in the table.

> **Definition**: The primary key of a relational table uniquely identifies each record in the table.

The correct primary key would be both columns.

Comment: It wont, you cant be sure that this IP will not be assigned to a different person next time - who can actually read the same page.

Comment: True, but I'm just telling him how he will get his required result. I'm assuming he knows this about IPs. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a table containing:

ID - unique generated number, this one will be PK
DATE - date of visit, which will help preserve unique visits from one IP
ARTICLE_ID - article id
IP - just IP

Now you create UNIQUE INDEX on: ARTICLE_ID, ARTICLE_ID, IP - probably in that order, but it depends on qyeries you are going to perform. In this way you will keep a track of unique IP on article per day.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key uniquely identify a row. A table can have at most one primary key, but more than one unique key. The output you get clearly demonstrates this since you have `article_id` as **primary key**